# Application hangs when debugged with Application Verifier

Tags: c++, application-verifier

I added my C++ application to Application Verifier. I am able to run it by directly executing the exe. But if I run it from VS 2013 or WinDbg, it just hangs with 0 CPU usage.

Even if I directly execute the exe, at a certain point it uses all my memory (10GB), and I have to restart the computer. So now I do not have a way to use Application Verifier to debug it.

There is only one line log created when my application starts. I do not see any other  logs in Application Verifier.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my case?

Comment: Maybe, a global initialization fiasco?

Answer (score 1):

If I disable the TLS option in Application Verifier, it will work in a debugger.